# Update Root Screen Tkinter Python

Tags: python, tkinter, updates

I've made a little program which helps me to divide people in multiple tasks, changing every hour (or more, or less). My code works perfeclty, but it would be nice if i had a user interface. I got to the point where I can add shifts and workers with the interface, but after adding a shift I'd like to see the name of the shift in a label (which wasn't there before I added the shift). I've tried to write a function that updates every second and only updating after a new shift is added, but I couldn't get it work properly.

This is my update function:

```
 def update_shifts(self):
    names_s = len(shifts)
    for i in range(names_s):
        b = Label(self.names_shift, text=shifts[i].get_name())
        b.grid(column=i,row=0)
```

`self.names_shift` is a frame, nothing wrong there.
(it's within the `__init__` of the root class.)

```
    self.names_shift = Frame(self)
    self.names_shift.pack(side=RIGHT)
```

`shifts` is a global list in which all the shift objects are stored.

Here is the bit where I call the update function (and where it probably goes wrong)

```
def add_shift(self):

    pop_up_2 = Add_Shift()
    pop_up_2.mainloop()
    self.update_shifts()
```

If I click on my "New Shift" button the `add_shift` function will be called.

Thanks!

Comment: Nothing obviously wrong. What is `self.names_shift`, and how do you call this function? Show some more code.

Comment: I updated my post! If you need anything more, please ask me!

Comment: I think the `AddShift` class is not really that relevant. You could mock it by just adding a `Shift` into the global list. What's more interesting it the frame and the label you want to add the information into.

Comment: I updated it, with the part where the frame is made. The label is made when the update function is called.

Comment: Okay, now what exactly does "not work properly"? Do you get an exception, is the callback not called, do the labels not appear or is the layout not as you expected? It might be a problem with mixing `pack` and `grid` layout on the frame wodget, but that's just a guess.

Comment: `TclError: can't invoke "label" command:  application has been destroyed` Is the error I get after I added a shift

Comment: Ah, okay, maybe the problem _was_ with the `Add_Frame` class after all... just another guess, but try extending `Toplevel` instead of `Tk`, and not calling `mainloop` in the callback.

Comment: Hmm yes. I've maded the `Add_Shift` class because i could easily grab the text in the entries so.  The `Add Shift` function works with a toplevel now. But when I press the 'ok' button, i have to call a function that makes a Shift object, but this function doesn't know the entries where it has to grab it's information.

Comment: It's working, thanks a lot!